# How to Overlap Container Corner Shades on flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to overlap the container corner shadow box shadow in multiple layers as shown in the picture.

What I want

[image: image description here]

I already made one layer
I don't know how to make a smaller second.

What I made

[image: image description here]

Please let me know if there's a way to solve it or if there's a better way

```
Container(
                        height: kMainPageContainerHeightSize,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: kDisabledColor,
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 16,
                            bottom: 16,
                            top: 16,
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: kBackgroundMainColor,
                              boxShadow: const [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: kDisabledColor,
                                  offset: Offset(20, 0),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: kBackgroundMainColor,
                              ),
                                // this is calendar
                              child: CustomTimeTable(
                                controller: viewmodel.customTimeTableController,
                                rowHeight: kMainPageContainerHeightSize / 9,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

I made it using overlapping containers and padding

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code to achieve the result:

[image]

```dart
Container(
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.grey[300]!),
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text('My Content')),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```